# how to combine two shapes in to make a drawable?

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, shapes

Basically I am trying to create this border for a textview and I cant seem to find anything online. I tried merging two shapes into one since thats basically a circle and a rectangle but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreiciated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this in drawable folder, and use it as background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="100dp" />
</shape>
```

Change `100dp` to what you like as well as the color.